# in capacitor android, how can I move splash screen spinner at the botton of the screen

Tags: android, ionic4, spinner, splash-screen, capacitor

how can I move ionic-angular capacitor splash screen spinner at the bottom of the of the screen for android

```
"plugins": {
"SplashScreen": {
  "launchShowDuration": 7000,
  "showSpinner": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation

[capacitor doc](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen)

> Full Screen & Immersive (Android only) You can enable splashFullScreen
> to hide status bar, or splashImmersive to hide both status bar and
> software navigation buttons. If both options are enabled
> splashImmersive takes priority, as it also fulfils splashFullScreen
> functionality.
>
> Configuration
> These config parameters are available in capacitor.config.json:

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 3000,
      "launchAutoHide": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffffff",
      "androidSplashResourceName": "splash",
      "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP",
      "androidSpinnerStyle": "large",
      "iosSpinnerStyle": "small",
      "spinnerColor": "#999999",
      "showSpinner": true,
      "splashFullScreen": true,
      "splashImmersive": true
    }
  }
}
```